# Sending payload for GET request in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, get, python-requests

To filter the output, I can send a JSON to the API, like :

```
curl -X GET https://api.mysite.com/user \ 
  -H "Authorization: XXXXX" \ 
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -d '{
    "q": {
      "name": {
          "eq": "0aslam0"
       }          
    }
  }'
```

The above works just fine. I am trying to send the same via python code using `requests` library.I tried the following code:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers, params=payload)
```

where

```
url = "https://api.mysite.com/user"
my_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'XXXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}
data = { 
    "q": {
        "name": {
            "eq": "0aslam0"
        }
    }
}
payload = json.dumps(data)
```

but `r.text` contains the output of a normal GET without applying filter. I logged the request, and saw that I was getting a redirect `301`. I don't understand my mistake.

**EDIT 1**

I changed the code to :

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers, json=payload)
```

@Martijn was right. Using `params` was wrong. But the above also didn't succeed. I also added a header `'User-Agent': 'curl/7.40.0'`, to see if that could work. No luck there as well.

**EDIT 2**

The API documentation says, filtering can be done by another method. Changing the url into:

```
GET /user?q%5Bname%5D%5Beq%5D=0aslam0 HTTP/1.1
```

It is HTML encoded. So I tried, to format my url into such a format and avoid sending the payload, like:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers)
```

And it works! So at least now I have a solution to my problem. But the question on how to send the payload (the method discussed above) for a GET request, still remains.

Comment: How is the Authorization header formed? Is there any signature included based on the request body perhaps?

Comment: Authorization header is a token generated for any developer of the API. No there is nothing such as a  signature that is dependent on the request body.

Comment: Then I'm pretty much out of ideas; the answer below produces a request close to what your `curl` command does (which is *rather strange* in that it uses `GET` rather than `POST`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added some more details in the question. I don't think you were wrong.

Comment: The URL you see from curl means you have `"q[name][eq]=0aslam0"` as query parameters in the URL. `curl` will *not* set those from the command line you've shown here; it'd already be part of the URL *or* you used a `--data-urlencode` command-line option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't use `--data-urlencode`. There was an additional doc, that said the filtering can be done without payload and just by changing the url. I was trying it out and in the process forgot that `GET /user?q%5Bname%5D%5Beq%5D=0aslam0 HTTP/1.1` was the output observed from the second method. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ah, yes, misunderstood you. Still not clear how the `curl` command ever worked though, and sending a body with a `GET` request is really not done in polite HTTP conversations (the spec says the server should ignore an entity body in that case). Sounds like you have a work-around for the issue here, however.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `-d`, the data is sent as a request *body*. `params` sends a URL query string, so that's the wrong argument to use.

Note that packaging along a request body with a `GET` method is technically a violation of the HTTP RFCs.

You'd have to send your request the `data` argument set instead, or pass in your dictionary to the `json` keyword argument and `requests` will encode that and set the right `Content-Type` header for you:

```
my_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'XXXXX',
}
data = { 
    "q": {
        "name": {
            "eq": "0aslam0"
        }
    }
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers, json=data)
```

Comment: @0aslam0: the same HTTP request is generated as what your `curl` command produces.  The only difference is the `User-Agent: curl/7.43.0` header, really.