# How download files when href values in their WebElements are a path to the same folder?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I try to automate the downloading of couples of text files. Operating manually, they can be downloaded by clicking on the buttons defined by the 2 following elements.

```
<a class="btn ...." href="/..../...../....../..../download" data-value="ext1">Download (.ext1) file</a>

<a class="btn ...." href="/..../...../....../..../download" data-value="ext2">Download (.ext2) file</a>
```

Please note that the two **href** values are the same and it is a path to a folder.

Using Selenium, I find the 2 FirefoxWebElements by

```
elem1=driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Download (.ext1) file")
elem2=driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Download (.ext2) file")
```

I can download the two files by
`elem1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` and
`elem2.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`,
then I have to find the two files in the download folder and I have to move them to the destination folder.
Note that I do not know the name of these files.

I would prefer to do it by requests to have them directly at their destination folder with the appropriate names.

```
url1=elem1.get_attribute('href')
r = requests.get(url1, allow_redirects=True)
open(destination1, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

and

```
url2=elem2.get_attribute('href')
r = requests.get(url2, allow_redirects=True)
open(destination2, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

But I get the same file (the first one) in both the cases since href value is the same.

*Would it be possible to download the two files directly to their destination folder? (may be additional parameters of requests.get or other ways?)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try tracking the network-tab on your browser when clicking the download-button and see what kind of request is sent. Maybe the request has "ext1" or "ext2" in the payload or something to separate between the files. [Sending payload for GET request in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847317/sending-payload-for-get-request-in-python)